# Masking zeros in Keras Embedding layer

Tags: tensorflow, keras

Below is simplified version of problem I'm having.

Sample data:

```
X = np.round(np.random.rand(10, 10) * 10).astype(np.int32)
y = np.round(np.random.rand(10)).astype(np.int32)
```

Model:

```
i = Input(shape=(10,), name='sentence_input', dtype='int32')
x = Embedding(1000, 10, mask_zero=True)(i)
o = LSTM(10)(x)
enc_model = Model(i, o)

i2 = Input(shape=(10,), dtype='int32')
x2 = enc_model(i2)
o2 = Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')(x2)

model = Model(i2, o2)
model.compile(optimizer='rmsprop', loss='binary_crossentropy')
model.fit(X, y, epochs=1)
```

I'm using Tensorflow 1.0.1 as Keras backend. Keras version 2.0.

I want to add masking but the moment `mask_zero=True` is added, it fails with error:

```
InvalidArgumentError: You must feed a value for placeholder tensor 'sentence_input_10' with dtype int32
[[Node: sentence_input_10 = Placeholder[dtype=DT_INT32, shape=[], _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"]()]]
```

I though adding `dtype='int32'` on both `Input` layers will fix the problem.

I need to have `enc_model` as a separate `Model`

Answer (score 0):

I think your input_dim of 1000 is too big, don't you only have 10 values as an input?
So it should be 12 (because you use mask_zero=True).

> mask_zero: Whether or not the input value 0 is a special "padding" value that should be masked out. This is useful when using recurrent layers which may take variable length input. If this is True then all subsequent layers in the model need to support masking or an exception will be raised. If mask_zero is set to True, as a consequence, index 0 cannot be used in the vocabulary (input_dim should equal |vocabulary| + 2).

Comment: I'm aware of the |vocabulary|+2 rule, but here is doesn't change anything. I've made an example easy enough for anyone to execute/experiment on their computer (assuming you're using Keras 2 and TF 1.0.*). If you change 1000 to 12, error is still there. Btw. I suspect is a Keras bug but just wanted to make sure I'm not doing something wrong.

Comment: I tried a bit around and it seems like the problem is that you want to use a model as a layer, which is not working. If you integrate the layers of your first model in the second one they work, so the layers don't seem to be the problem. Can I ask why you need to seperated models?
A soltution would be perhaps to write your own keras layer and use that in the second model.

Comment: I need it separated because my enc_model is reused in 2 separate inputs that have to share the same weights. Before I've tried rewriting it using Sequential and it still gives the same error. The code is based on https://keras.io/getting-started/functional-api-guide/ , example code snippet called "Shared vision model". I'm doing exactly the same and it works until  masking is added.

Comment: I just checked it again and it seems like its running now, did you contacted the keras team about it?

Comment: It was spotted before and fixed in Keras version 2.0.3. Probably [this commit](https://github.com/fchollet/keras/commit/c3c634f4b1f76dc6ab64904deaa871650ceb0de5).